# Is it possible to chain arrow functions context that declared in object

Tags: javascript

How can I chain arrow functions that are called from (Map) object?

The "this" context is always ignored when I'm trying to do this:

```js
function bar() {
  console.log("bar");
  return this;
}

function vaz() {
  console.log("vaz");
  return this;
}

const configMap = new Map([
  [
    "Document",
    {
      action: () => bar(),
      process: () => vaz()
    }
  ]
  //...
]);
// Error - Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'process')
configMap.get("Document").action().process();
```

I know the arrow functions don't use the `this` they're called with, they completely ignore it. Is that even possible or is there another solution?

Comment: Object composition maybe?

Comment: Why not use non-arrow functions? You're allowed to, you know...

Comment: @HereticMonkey I just wanted to know if it's possible somehow...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `this` needs to refer to the map value object for chaining to work. This works very naturally if you simply change the `action` and `process` to normal functions and return `this` from inside them. (Not from `bar` or `vaz`, since they aren't being called with any `this`)

```js
function bar() {
  console.log("bar");
}

function vaz() {
  console.log("vaz");
}

const configMap = new Map([
  [
    "Document",
    {
      action: function() { bar(); return this; },
      process: function() { vaz(); return this; },
    }
  ]
  //...
]);
configMap.get("Document").action().process();
```

If you *must* use arrow functions and want this to work, you'll have to put the document object into a variable and return it instead of `this`.

```js
function bar() {
  console.log("bar");
}

function vaz() {
  console.log("vaz");
}

const documentObj = {
  action: () => { bar(); return documentObj; },
  process: () => { vaz(); return documentObj; },
};
const configMap = new Map([
  ["Document", documentObj]
  //...
]);
configMap.get("Document").action().process();
```

Without declaring it outside, you'd need an IIFE.

```js
function bar() {
  console.log("bar");
}

function vaz() {
  console.log("vaz");
}


const configMap = new Map([
  [
    "Document",
    (() => {
      const documentObj = {
        action: () => { bar(); return documentObj; },
        process: () => { vaz(); return documentObj; },
      };
      return documentObj;
    })(),
  ]
  //...
]);
configMap.get("Document").action().process();
```

But a plain `function` would be easier, as in the first snippet.